# Overlapping annotated regions among repetitive families of human genome

Tags: dna, human-genetics, dna-sequencing, gene-annotation, repeatitive-sequence

I am studying the *repetitive elements in the human genome* and I have come to know that some genomic locations are not uniquely described by a single repeat family. What's behind this uncertainty? Does it account, for example, for the variability among individuals? or is it a fact deriving from the limitations of our current technology?

The reason behind this question is a practical issue. My team is analysing the composition of some sequencing data and is mostly interested in the repetitive elements of human DNA. I can use the repeat masks that I download from UCSC database and count their abundance. My problem is that some repeat masks overlap at specific locations in the annotation track.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] and then consult the Help on Asking Questions. I think that your question desperately needs clarification with an example. When you present your example be sure to provide a link. Without this I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: Can you give some motivation of why regions _would_ be covered by a single annotation? For example, a coding portion of a gene is annotated as a gene, a transcript, an exon, and a CDS. That's 4 distinct annotations! If it's a transposase, it will also be annotated as a transposon, for 5 annotations. Having overlapping annotations is to be expected. I supposed you might mean _repeat family annotations_, but similar logic applies. Recombination of repeats etc. is rampant: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3242629/, https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.07.02.163816v1.full

Comment: Yes @Maxilimiam, I meant _repeat_family_annotations_. If I understand it correctly, you are alluding to the fact that some repeat families are associated to transposons elements and, as consequence of that, they are 'mobile' elements of the genome so it makes sense if some genomic locations can have multiple annotations.

Comment: @David, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @AVO on the order of 50% of the human genome is repeats. Of that, [>80% of the repetitive contents are mobile genetic elements (MGEs; see Table 1 of linked paper)](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abj6987). So yes, when you talk about "repetitive DNA" you are generally speaking talking about MGEs. But the logic is actually that depending on what you mean by "annotation", you might have the same element annotated as a LINE, a SINE, an Alu, etc. (all MGE types), because these are sometimes chimeric or recombinant.